Installing VSCode Server via Remote-SSH pauses for many minutes
When I open a Remote-SSH connection to a new Linux server, there is a ~5minute pause before the download begins.
How can I get more information on what the server is waiting for?
The Remote-SSH log shows a ~5min delay between "Installing" and "Downloading" messages (see annoated log below).  What's it doing during that time?
[11:51:52.609] [server] Checking /store/.vscode-server/cli/servers/Stable-dc96b837cf6bb4af9cd736aa3af08cf8279f7685/log.txt and /store/.vscode-server/cli/servers/Stable-dc96b837cf6bb4af9cd736aa3af08cf8279f7685/pid.txt for a running server...

### Install starts
[11:51:53.211] [server] Installing and setting up Visual Studio Code Server...

### Nothing happens for almost 5 minutes, then it continues
[11:56:16.674] [server] Downloading Visual Studio Code server -> /tmp/.tmpwJyFmY/stable
[11:56:16.676] [server] server download progress: 0/56657077 (0%)
[11:56:20.589] [server] server download progress: 2099544/56657077 (4%)

In case it helps, here is the full log up to the point where the server begins downloading.
[11:51:42.739] Log Level: 2
[11:51:42.748] SSH Resolver called for "ssh-remote+58", attempt 1
[11:51:42.752] "remote.SSH.useLocalServer": false
[11:51:42.752] "remote.SSH.useExecServer": true
[11:51:42.752] "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": false
[11:51:42.753] "remote.SSH.remotePlatform": {"myhost":"linux"}
[11:51:42.753] "remote.SSH.path": undefined
[11:51:42.753] "remote.SSH.configFile": undefined
[11:51:42.753] "remote.SSH.useFlock": true
[11:51:42.753] "remote.SSH.lockfilesInTmp": false
[11:51:42.754] "remote.SSH.localServerDownload": auto
[11:51:42.754] "remote.SSH.remoteServerListenOnSocket": false
[11:51:42.754] "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": false
[11:51:42.754] "remote.SSH.defaultExtensions": []
[11:51:42.754] "remote.SSH.loglevel": 2
[11:51:42.754] "remote.SSH.enableDynamicForwarding": true
[11:51:42.754] "remote.SSH.enableRemoteCommand": false
[11:51:42.754] "remote.SSH.serverPickPortsFromRange": {}
[11:51:42.756] "remote.SSH.serverInstallPath": {"myhost":"/data"}
[11:51:42.759] VS Code version: 1.89.1
[11:51:42.759] Remote-SSH version: remote-ssh@0.110.1
[11:51:42.759] win32 x64
[11:51:42.777] SSH Resolver called for host: myhost
[11:51:42.777] Setting up SSH remote "myhost"
[11:51:42.781] Using commit id "dc96b837cf6bb4af9cd736aa3af08cf8279f7685" and quality "stable" for server
[11:51:42.785] Install and start server if needed
[11:51:42.796] Checking ssh with "C:\windows\system32\ssh.exe -V"
[11:51:42.799] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\windows\system32\ssh.exe ENOENT
[11:51:42.800] Checking ssh with "C:\windows\ssh.exe -V"
[11:51:42.801] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\windows\ssh.exe ENOENT
[11:51:42.801] Checking ssh with "C:\windows\System32\Wbem\ssh.exe -V"
[11:51:42.802] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\windows\System32\Wbem\ssh.exe ENOENT
[11:51:42.802] Checking ssh with "C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\ssh.exe -V"
[11:51:42.803] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\ssh.exe ENOENT
[11:51:42.803] Checking ssh with "C:\windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe -V"
[11:51:43.239] > OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, 
[11:51:43.239] > LibreSSL 3.0.2

[11:51:43.250] Running script with connection command: "C:\windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe" -T -D 55744 myhost bash
[11:51:43.253] Terminal shell path: C:\windows\System32\cmd.exe
[11:51:43.815] > ]0;C:\windows\System32\cmd.exe
[11:51:43.816] Got some output, clearing connection timeout
[11:51:44.048] > load pubkey "C:\\Users\\myusername/.ssh/id_ed25519": invalid format
[11:51:44.932] > Warning: Permanently added 'myhost.mydomain.net' (ECDSA) to the l
> ist of known hosts.
[11:51:45.745] > ##----------------------------------------------------------------------------
> # WARNING: This is a private system.  Do not attempt to login unless you are 
> # an authorized user.  Any access and use may be monitored and can result in 
> # criminal or civil prosecution under applicable law.
> #----------------------------------------------------------------------------
> #
> #
[11:51:47.252] > a654ebc89e1e: running
[11:51:47.385] > Installing to /data/.vscode-server...
[11:51:47.415] > a654ebc89e1e%%1%%
[11:51:47.432] > Downloading with wget
[11:51:49.836] > Download complete
[11:51:49.868] > a654ebc89e1e%%2%%
> tar --version:   
[11:51:49.905] > tar (GNU tar) 1.34
> Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
> License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
> This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
> There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
> 
> Written by John Gilmore and Jay Fenlason.
[11:51:50.870] > code 1.89.1 (commit dc96b837cf6bb4af9cd736aa3af08cf8279f7685)
[11:51:50.906] > Starting VS Code CLI... "/data/.vscode-server/code-dc96b837cf6bb4af9cd736aa3af0
> 8cf8279f7685" command-shell --cli-data-dir "/data/.vscode-server/cli" --on-port
>  --parent-process-id 342488 &> "/data/.vscode-server/.cli.dc96b837cf6bb4af9cd73
> 6aa3af08cf8279f7685.log" < /dev/null
> printenv:
[11:51:50.915] > 
>     SHELL=/bin/sh
>     PWD=/home/root
>     LOGNAME=root
>     HOME=/home/root
>     VSCODE_AGENT_FOLDER=/data/.vscode-server
>     SSH_CONNECTION=10.207.137.211 55745 10.229.130.226 22
>     USER=root
>     SHLVL=0
>     SSH_CLIENT=10.207.137.211 55745 22
[11:51:50.923] > 
>     PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
>     OLDPWD=/data/.vscode-server
>     _=/usr/bin/printenv
[11:51:50.949] > 
> Spawned remote CLI: 342552
[11:51:50.970] > 
[11:51:51.078] > Waiting for server log...
[11:51:51.255] > Waiting for server log...
[11:51:51.422] > Waiting for server log...
[11:51:51.503] > a654ebc89e1e: start
> SSH_AUTH_SOCK====
> DISPLAY====
> listeningOn==127.0.0.1:41839==
> osReleaseId==custom-linux==
> arch==aarch64==
> vscodeArch==arm64==
> bitness==64==
> tmpDir==/tmp==
> platform==linux==
> unpackResult==success==
[11:51:51.517] > 
> didLocalDownload==0==
> downloadTime==2458==
> installTime==956==
> serverStartTime==579==
[11:51:51.543] > 
> execServerToken==a1a11a11-1a1a-111a-a1a1-11111111a11a==
> a654ebc89e1e: end
[11:51:51.544] Received install output: 
SSH_AUTH_SOCK====
DISPLAY====
listeningOn==127.0.0.1:41839==
osReleaseId==custom-linux==
arch==aarch64==
vscodeArch==arm64==
bitness==64==
tmpDir==/tmp==
platform==linux==
unpackResult==success==
didLocalDownload==0==
downloadTime==2458==
installTime==956==
serverStartTime==579==
execServerToken==a1a11a11-1a1a-111a-a1a1-11111111a11a==

[11:51:51.545] Remote server is listening on port 41839
[11:51:51.546] Parsed server configuration: {"serverConfiguration":{"remoteListeningOn":{"port":41839},"osReleaseId":"custom-linux","arch":"aarch64","sshAuthSock":"","display":"","tmpDir":"/tmp","platform":"linux","execServerToken":"a1a11a11-1a1a-111a-a1a1-11111111a11a"},"downloadTime":2458,"installTime":956,"serverStartTime":579,"installUnpackCode":"success"}
[11:51:51.546] ** Note: Support for architecture "aarch64" is in preview **
[11:51:51.569] Starting forwarding server. local port 55751 -> socksPort 55744 -> remotePort 41839
[11:51:51.570] Forwarding server listening on port 55751
[11:51:51.570] Waiting for ssh tunnel to be ready
[11:51:51.572] [Forwarding server port 55751] Got connection 0
[11:51:51.573] Tunneled port 41839 to local port 55751
[11:51:51.574] Resolved "ssh-remote+myhost" to "port 55751"
[11:51:51.576] Initizing new exec server for ssh-remote+myhost
[11:51:51.576] Resolving exec server at port 55751
[11:51:51.599] [Forwarding server port 55751] Got connection 1
[11:51:52.356] Exec server for ssh-remote+myhost created and cached
[11:51:52.360] ------




[11:51:52.609] [server] Checking /data/.vscode-server/cli/servers/Stable-dc96b837cf6bb4af9cd736aa3af08cf8279f7685/log.txt and /data/.vscode-server/cli/servers/Stable-dc96b837cf6bb4af9cd736aa3af08cf8279f7685/pid.txt for a running server...
[11:51:53.211] [server] Installing and setting up Visual Studio Code Server...
[11:56:16.674] [server] Downloading Visual Studio Code server -> /tmp/.tmpwJyFmY/stable
[11:56:16.676] [server] server download progress: 0/56657077 (0%)
[11:56:20.589] [server] server download progress: 2099544/56657077 (4%)


What's the code that's being run on the server? Error messages are far more useful with accompanying source to judge what went wrong.

It is vscode-server remote-ssh. The log contents are from the remote-ssh. There are no error messages. I need to enable additional logging to see what's happening.  The running process is: "/data/.vscode-server/code-dc96b837cf6bb4af9cd736aa3af08cf8279f7685 command-shell --cli-data-dir /data/.vscode-server/cli --parent-process-id 233426 --on-port"
